# Applications not found in Office 365

Tags: azure, authentication, office365

Morning;

I have an issue with Azure AD and Office 365.

I developed an application and I used Office 365 for authentication.

The problem is When I make consent for application to use my profile information etc, I can not found the granted application in my Office 365 account.

[EDIT]

I look for autorisation in this section

[image]

In Azure I made this configuration

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify the following: 1) Places you looked at to see list of granted apps. 2) Configuration details of your in Azure AD. Is it web app, native app etc.

Comment: Yeah, You are right, I updated my post. is there enough information now?

Answer (score 0):

I wish you had posted the URL but the first screenshot seems to come from https://portal.office.com/account/#apps, which is the Office 365 portal.

Azure AD applications are listed at https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications

Comment: Yes, Firstly I registred the app in azure, and then I enable Authentication using Azure AD which use Office 365 to log in users, so from what I understand how can a user list the authorized apps in his portal?

Comment: Did you check the [2nd link above](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications)? Your app will be listed on that page.